# Cocoa Code Error

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

this code Iphone SDK 3.0 version or later

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kTitleKey];
```

but it gives error
**request for member 'textLabel' in something not a structure or union**

I also try

```
cell.text = [[menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:kTitleKey];
```

but also not working. Can anybody help regarding this

Thanks 
Deepika

Comment: where and how you declare and initialize your cell object?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the class definition for the cell object, what type of object is it by the way?  Does it have a property named "text" or "textLabel" or something similar?  Since you are getting build errors I would guess not so maybe there is a different property altogether you should be looking for.  Anyways I'm rambling a bit but the class definition for whatever type of object cell is should have your answer.